# how to perform sum and count on dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe with ID, type, and the area I would like to perform two operations at once

```
ID         Type         Area     
1           Aa          0.02    
2           Ag          0.12    
2           Ag          0.14    
2           Ag          0.80    
2           Bm          0.20    
2           Xm          0.13
```

The expected outcome is

```
ID          Type       count      area     
1           Aa           1        0.02    
2           Ag           3        1.06 (sum)    
2           Bm           1        0.20    
2           Xm           1        0.13
```

I have up to 100-150 ID and type, count and basal area varies for each type with the same ID, what would be the best approach to perform sum and count same time and keep type and ID  in dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't accepted any of the answers! Didn't any serve your purpose?

Answer (score 7):

**1) Base R -- aggregate** Counts are just the sum of a constant column of ones so using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we add such a column and aggregate using `sum`.  No packages are used.

```
aggregate(cbind(Count, Area) ~ ID + Type, transform(DF, Count = 1), sum)
```

giving:

```
  ID Type Count Area
1  1   Aa     1 0.02
2  2   Ag     3 1.06
3  2   Bm     1 0.20
4  2   Xm     1 0.13
```

**2) Base R -- by** An approach using only base R that does not rely on the trick of adding a column of ones is to use `by`.  The `by` call produces a list of class `by` and the `do.call("rbind", ...)` converts that to a data frame.

```
do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF[1:2], with, 
  data.frame(ID = ID[1], Type = Type[1], Count = length(ID), Area = sum(Area))))
```

giving:

```
  ID Type Count Area
1  1   Aa     1 0.02
2  2   Ag     3 1.06
3  2   Bm     1 0.20
4  2   Xm     1 0.13
```

**3) sqldf**  SQL allows the separate and simultaneous application of count and sum.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select ID, Type, count(*) as Count, sum(Area) as Area
  from DF
  group by 1, 2")
```

giving:

```
  ID Type Count Area
1  1   Aa     1 0.02
2  2   Ag     3 1.06
3  2   Bm     1 0.20
4  2   Xm     1 0.13
```

**4) data.table** The data.table package can also be used.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, .(Count = .N, Area = sum(Area)), by = "ID,Type"]
```

giving:

```
   ID Type Count Area
1:  1   Aa     1 0.02
2:  2   Ag     3 1.06
3:  2   Bm     1 0.20
4:  2   Xm     1 0.13
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ID         Type         Area     
1           Aa          0.02    
2           Ag          0.12    
2           Ag          0.14    
2           Ag          0.80    
2           Bm          0.20    
2           Xm          0.13 "

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks it works, Smart solution. Only the ID does not appear in ascending order e.g 1,2,3,... instead organizes in alphabetical order.

Comment: The question did not specify whether ID was numeric or not but in the Note in the answer we did showing it as numeric. If what you have is different then convert it to numeric first. This shows why it is important to provide a reproducible example in the question as was done in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `dplyr`.  Packages are used

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID, Type) %>%
   summarise(count = n(), Area = sum(Area))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Type  count  Area
#  <int> <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1     1 Aa        1  0.02
#2     2 Ag        3  1.06
#3     2 Bm        1  0.2 
#4     2 Xm        1  0.13
```

---

or with `by` from `base R` - Note that `base R` includes some packages as well...

```
by(df1['Area'], df1[1:2], FUN = function(x) cbind(count = nrow(x), Area = sum(x)))
```

---

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Type = c("Aa", 
"Ag", "Ag", "Ag", "Bm", "Xm"), Area = c(0.02, 0.12, 0.14, 0.8, 
0.2, 0.13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting an error "Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace"

Answer (score 2):

If your data is large, I recommend `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Area=sum(Area), Count=.N), .(ID, Type)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility in `plyr`:

```r
library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(ID,Type), summarize, Count=length(Area), Area=sum(Area))

#   ID Type Count  Area
# 1  1   Aa     1  0.02
# 2  2   Ag     3  1.06
# 3  2   Bm     1  0.20
# 4  2   Xm     1  0.13
```